# Performant way to get td values for each row in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a normal table ( 6 columns, multiple rows, filled with data). I am currently trying to gather the table data into an array:

```
  tableData(0) = "1, Hans, Testperson, Munich, Germany"
  tableData(1) = "2, Petra, Testperson, Hamburg, Germany"
```

So the index of the array shall indicate which tr the data was taken from and on the right side the td values are in a string, sperated by `,`.

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
function getTableData() {
   var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#tableId tr");
   var data = []
   for (var j = 1; j < tableRows.length; j++) {
      var rowColumns = tableRows [j].querySelectorAll("td")
      var columnData = ""
      for (var k = 1; k < rowColumns.length; k++) {
         columnData = columnData + rowColumns[k].innerText
         if (k < rowColumns.length-1) {columnData = columnData + ","}
      }
      data.push(columnData)
   }
 }
```

Its working as expected but whenever the table has more than 1000 rows its getting very slow. Is there a better way of doing it with only pure JS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the table element api to access [rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) and cells to avoid nested queries.

Either using map to concatenate the `cell.innerText`

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableId');

const data = [];
for (const row of tableBody.rows) {
  data.push([...row.cells].map((c) => c.innerText).join(', '));
}

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>id</td><td>first</td><td>last</td><td>city</td><td>country</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Petra</td><td>Müller</td><td>Hamburg</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Hans</td><td>Schneider</td><td>Munich</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Jan</td><td>Meyer</td><td>Düsseldorf</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>Tura</td><td>Fischer</td><td>Leipzig</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or gathering into a string.

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableId');

const data = [];
for (const row of tableBody.rows) {
  let rowData = '';
  for (const cell of row.cells){
    rowData += `${cell.innerText}, `;
  }
  data.push(rowData.slice(0,-2));
}

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>id</td><td>first</td><td>last</td><td>city</td><td>country</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Petra</td><td>Müller</td><td>Hamburg</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Hans</td><td>Schneider</td><td>Munich</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Jan</td><td>Meyer</td><td>Düsseldorf</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>Tura</td><td>Fischer</td><td>Leipzig</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

It will probably be faster to use map + join for the column loop rather than append bits to a string:

```
function getTableData() {
  var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#tableId tr");
  var data = [];
  for (var j = 1; j < tableRows.length; j++) {
    data.push([...tableRows[j].querySelectorAll("td")].map((c) => c.innerText).join(","));
  }
}
```